# Active states for all items clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am using the US-Map plugin by newsignature (https://newsignature.github.io/us-map/). I have built out a chart to compare different state laws per state click.

Right now I can compare 3 different states and the user has the ability to close out a state and click a different state for comparison.

When you click a state you get an active state. Once you click another state that active state goes away and to that other state. I cannot figure out how to tie in an active state for each state clicked.

```
$('#' + data.name).css('fill', '#0075b9');
```

That line makes the state active on click. I would assume this needs to be applied to all states clicked, but adding it to the click state does nothing.

Here is the fiddle with the current functionality set up: https://jsfiddle.net/yurtqy87/1/

Any ideas?

Note: I only put in data New York, California, Georgia, Alaska, Alabama, and Florida to save time. Clicking any other state won't yield any results in the columns below.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what effect you're going for, but when you click on 'California' in your fiddle, the line of code you have above is trying set the css on something with an id of 'ca'. But there is nothing in the DOM with an id of 'ca'. if you debug the javascript you can type $('#ca') into the console and you get 'null'.

Comment: Sorry, the js file I was working on I added one line of code that gave each state an identifier that tied to that one line. I edited the fiddle and now you will see on a click, each click creates a div for that specific state. You will also see that now each state that is clicked stays on an active state until the new one is clicked. The idea is to have every state that is clicked to show up as active.

https://jsfiddle.net/yurtqy87/10/

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the library API and methods and you have to wing it. I would use an array to store the selected stated.

```
var selectedStates = ['XX', 'YY', 'ZZ'];
```

Upon creation you could color them differently

```
stateSpecificStyles: {
        'XX': {fill: 'red'},
        'YY': {fill: 'red'},
        'ZZ': {fill: 'red'}
    }
```

When a state is clicked, if it is in the selection you should remove it, if not you should at it

**Remove** in 'click' handler:

```
var toRemove = data.name;

selectedStates = jQuery.grep(selectedStates, function(value) {
  return value != toRemove;
});
```

After removal or addition of a state, just refresh the map and your UI.

Comment: how would I reload the map?

Comment: Use re-initialize the map with the new options (where you added/removed the state)